# Como satisfacer dos condiciones al mismo tiempo

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Buenas tardes, supongamos que tengo una lista de alumnos con la lista de materias que aprobaron, y quiero seleccionar el nombre de los que aprobaron matemática y lengua, si yo hago:

```
SELECT nombreAlumno
FROM alumno
WHERE aprobo = matematica
AND
aprobo = lengua
```

Esto no daría ningún resultado ya que aprobó tendría que tener esos dos valores al mismo tiempo, y no cada uno por separado, hay alguna consulta con la cual poder hacer esto de una manera fácil y rápida? Me explico, necesitaría algo como la división de álgebra relacional, en la cual se da un dato a comparar, con una lista, en la que el primer dato debe estar relacionada con todos los datos de la lista. Uso mariadb.

Comment: Puedes tratar con un OR en vez del AND

Comment: Pero necesito que satisfaga los dos casos, no solo uno

Comment: Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y pongas tus tablas para ver como está conformada tu base de datos, y poderte dar una mejor solución. Sin ver las tablas no podemos saber lo que tienes hecho y como es estructura de la BD y por tanto no podemos proponerte una consulta que se ajuste a lo que tienes y necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conozco la estructura de tu base de datos, pero creo que lo que necesitas es el operador in y subqueries. Entiendo que tienes una tabla de alumnos, una tabla de materias y una tercera tabla la cual es la relación de las dos primeras, es decir, sus cuenta con llave foránea a alumnos y llave foránea a materias. Si es ese el caso, el query podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE alumno.id IN (SELECT alumno_id FROM aprobadas WHERE  materia_id = 'MATEMATICAS') AND alumno.id IN (SELECT alumno_id FROM aprobadas WHERE materia_id = 'LENGUA')
```

Con este query comprobarías si el alumno está en la lista de los que aprobaron matemáticas y a su vez en la lista de los que aprobaron lengua. Vale la pena mencionar que no es del todo necesario usar el operador IN y comparar el id del alumno contra toda la lista de alumnos que aprobaron, ya que podría compararse directamente el id del alumno, si el dato está en ambas tablas:

```
SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE alumno.id = (SELECT alumno_id FROM aprobadas WHERE alumno_id = alumno.id AND materia_id = 'MATEMATICAS') AND alumno.id = (SELECT alumno_id FROM aprobadas WHERE alumno_id = alumno.id AND materia_id = 'LENGUA')
```

Espero haber interpretado correctamente tu duda.

Comment: Es exacto lo que necesito, gracias!

Comment: @Ramiro, en StackOverflow, la idea es marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te haya servido. Esto ayudará a la comunidad (sobre todo a quienes lleguen a este tema luego a través de una búsqueda) a saber que hay una solución para el problema planteado y a reconocer fácilmente esa solución.

Answer (score 0):

La [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20879/21%20respuesta) de lfentanes es correcta, pero quizás no sea la más óptima si tienes muchos registros, te dejo esta otra opción:

```
select a.*
  from alumno a
       inner join aprobadas am on am.idAlumno = a.idAlumno and am.materia = 'MATEMATICAS'
       inner join aprobadas al on al.idAlumno = a.idAlumno and al.materia = 'LENGUA';
```

Desconozco las capacidades del optimizador de `mysql` o `mariadb`, pero en algunos motores escribir la consulta de esta manera hará la diferencia.

Comment: Gracias por responder, luego intentare esa solucion, me falta pulir un poco mis join.

Answer (score 0):

Para ello puedes usar IN en tu clausura WHERE y listo.

```
SELECT a.* FROM alumno a JOIN aprobados ap on ap.id_alumno = a.idAlumno
WHERE ap.materia IN ("Lengua", "Matematica");
```